# Is there any cleaner way to assign value if array key isset?

Tags: php

I think the below is a very **standard procedure** that everyone had written it a hundred times in any of their applications:

```
$orderByColumnName = '';
if (isset($this->urlParams()['orderby']) {
    $orderByColumnName = $this->urlParams()['orderby']; 
}

$this->someSortingFunction($orderByColumnName);
```

I've been doing such way numerous time, I'm feeling sick of it.

There's some kind of like **global** understanding that **suppressing error is evil**.
Despite the code can be written so clean by just:

```
$this->someSortingFunction(@$this->urlParams()['orderby']);
```

And a ternary shorthand `true ?: false;` is something close but not useful in this situation because there's no *presumed isset check* on the condition. Thus we still have to write:

```
$orderByColumnName = !empty($this->urlParams()['orderby'])?$this->urlParams()['orderby']:'';
```

So how exactly you guys handle this situation? `if` all the way? Is there any other *smarter* way that you could share?

Comment: sounds like a job for code review

Comment: what about `$this->someSortingFunction(array_key_exists('orderby', $this->urlParams()));`

Comment: or we can define a separate static function and call it everytime we need to use empty or isset ? -- will like to add that as one answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not change how the `urlParams()` method operates? PHP doesn't have true method overloading, but you can fake it inside the method.

```
public function urlParam($param = null) {
  //lets assume $internal_array is 
  //your object's internal array sent through urlParam()
  if(is_null($param)) {
     return $internal_array;
  } else {
    return isset($internal_array[$param]) ? $internal_array[$param] : '';
  }
}
```

Doing this would let you you keep your existing code compatible with `$this->urlParams()['some_param']`usage while enabling you to refactor everything to `$this->urlParams('some_param')`.

Comment: I think method overloading is getting me to the point. I had been thinking about having an optional argument for `urlParams()`, to give it a totally different behaviour. But it is a private property getter at the first place, I just thought I won't change it to something complex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a separate static function which returns `NULL` if value is not present in an array.

```
public static function value($key, $list, $default = NULL) {
  if (is_array($list)) {
    return array_key_exists($key, $list) ? $list[$key] : $default;
  }
 return $default;
}
```

Can call this everytime we need to use `empty(), isset(), array_key_exists()`

```
$this->someSortingFunction(value('orderby', $this->urlParams()));
```